# How to write/read an incomplete Certificate Signing Request with OpenSSL's C library?

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I'm currently working on x509 certificates.
What I want to do is, considering a user who has his own certificate and a Certification Authority:

1. Generate a Certificate Signing Request with the public key of the user.
2. Sign this CSR with the CA's private key.

I know how to do this if I know both the user's private key and the CA's private key: using `X509_REQ_set_pubkey(req, user_private_key)` and `X509_REQ_sign(req, CA_private_key, EVP_sha256())`.

However, the user will not know the CA's private key, and the CA will not know the user's private key. Thus, the user has to use `X509_REQ_set_pubkey` function, then somehow store the CSR and send it to the CA.
And that is where I have a problem: the user can write its CSR in a file via the `PEM_write_X509_REQ` function but the CA can not read it via the `PEM_read_X509_REQ` function since the CSR had been written unsigned.

Does someone know a way to achieve what I want ?

Thanks by advance !

--- Edit ---

Actually, this question is a bit too long and could be rephrase: "What is the C-library equivalent to OpenSSL's command `openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem` ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I figured out that my questions resulted from a misunderstanding (from myself) of how a CSR is made: it is composed of some information about the subject (including of course his public key) and it is **signed with his private key** (which I did not understand). Then, the function `X509_REQ_sign` do not take as argument the CA's private key but the subject's one. Thus, I can use this function and store/read my CSR as usal using `PEM_write_X509_REQ` and `PEM_read_X509_REQ`.